# Incorrect view Django

Tags: python, django, view

I have a GET part of the view:

```
    def get(self, request, event_id, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial={})
        evnt = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        cmnt = Comments_events.objects.filter(event_cmnt_id=event_id)

        ANSWR = HOW TO GET?

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'event': evnt, 'comments': cmnt, 'answers': ANSWR, 'form': form})
```

Two models:

```
    class Comments_events(models.Model):

       text_cmnt = models.TextField

       author_cmnt = models.ForeignKey(
           settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
           null=True,
           blank=True
       )

    class Answers(models.Model):

      comment_answr = models.ForeignKey('Comments_events')

      text_cmnt = models.TextField

      author_cmnt = models.ForeignKey(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          null=True,
          blank=True
      )
```

On the page I post a post, a comment to it, and I want to display the answers to the comments.

**Tell me how to correctly make GET "answr" in a view to display it in html?**

Comment: clarify your question and post your models.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple use related `_set` in the template, example:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {% for answer in comment.answers_set.all %}
      {{ answer }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that it really works. thanks for teaching me)